# Angular: setTimeout delay duration increases every time it is invoked

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using setTimeout in ngOnInit function in my component as I am setting some properties on a few children components (the template ref would be null without the delay).
However this delay, irrespective of the number provided to the setTimeout, increases by double every time this component is created. The first time the component is rendered, the timeout delays for 100ms approx. However after a few times of opening and closing the component (it's in a dialog), the delay increases upto 8000ms and beyond.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    setTimeout(() {
        // Access template variables here
    }, 0);
}
```

This problem is not exclusive to the component lifecycle *ngOnInit) as I am facing the same issue throughout my application as I use setTimeout as a pseduo *sleep* function. The function is not connected to any component, service or any class at all, it is exported independently.

Comment: _"as I use setTimeout as a pseduo sleep function."_ - If you need `setTimeout` to make your stuff work, then there"s something conceptually flawed

Comment: Maybe try to use different lifecycle hook :)

Comment: Andreas, I am working with a graph library (cytoscape) and need the sleep function as a lot of changes within the cytoscape graph do not reflect immediately. Not a fan of using setTimeout myself, but I don't see a way around it.

Comment: Maybe it's because your setTimeout is never cleared so it makes multiple instances of it ? Try to clear your setTimeout inside ngOnDestroy.

Comment: @MateuszŚcigała Thanks. I don't know much about Angular but I tried some of the lifecycles hooks and ngAfterContentChecked seemed to work. Had to use a ChangeDetector though as the properties being changed in the child component (after the child component is rendered) caused "ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError"

Comment: This may be a side effect of other `setTimeout`s you are executing. Remember `setTimeout` pushes the callback to the end of the event loop queue, behind anything else that has been pushed on there. If the timeout hasn't expired by the time it gets popped, it goes to the back again. By the sound of *"I use setTimeout as a pseudo sleep function"* I think you may be liberally pushing things on to the queue. You may need to save the id and clean up your `setTimeouts` if they are no longer needed.

Comment: You can also use `queueMicrotask` to push the task onto another queue that will be executed before popping the next task from the main queue.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my *sleep()* function that was using setTimeout, as seen below

```
new Promise(resolve => timeout = setTimeout(resolve, ms));
```

to use only Promises

```
new Promise.resolve(null).then(()=>{});
```

@Chris Hamiltons comment led to me scouring Google about microtasks and I remembered an article I had come across about **[ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError](https://hackernoon.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4)**. Specifically this part,

> The setTimeout function schedules a macrotask then will be executed in the following VM turn. It is also possible to executed the update in the current VM turn but after the current synchronous code has finished executing by using then callback of a promise:
>
> Instead of a macrotask Promise.then creates a micrtotask. The microtask queue is processed after the current synchronous code has finished executing hence the update to the property will happen after the verification step.

Also created a new function to use `setTimeout` wherein I also cancel the timeout as soon as it is done with its execution.

```
delay = async (ms: number) => {
    let timeout: number;
    await new Promise(resolve => timeout = setTimeout(resolve, ms));
    clearTimeout(timeout);
}
```

I use this only when I need explicit and precise delays.